# Database Error in rpc request (from remote system.sql) 002003 (42502):

Tags: rpc, dbt

I have recently started working and learning dbt cloud as I was following up on its documentation regarding connecting and working with Snowflake and dbt together . I am unable to build models on top of other models as CTE. The lineage shows correct graph but dbt is unable to build the model. The error is as follows:

Database Error in rpc request (from remote system.sql) 002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error: Object 'INTERNS_TRAINING.DBT_NMARRIA.STG_CUSTOMERS' does not exist or not authorized.

Here my INTERS_TRAINING is my schema in snowflake I have given right access and authorisation . Here is the link of the official documentation I am following as hands on:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/quickstarts/dbt-cloud/snowflake:

Ref Image:
[Lineage graph is showing fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6RGt.png) 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAduS.png)

What I am expecting is as follows
[correct lineage that I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/156x2.png)